# Swift: Binary Tree Search with int not in tree

Tags: swift, binary-tree

I am going through Ray Weynderlich's Swift Algo Club files and he uses this code for getting the tree height:

```
   func findTreeHeight() -> Int {

        if isLeaf {
            return 0
        } else {
            return 1 + max(leftChild?.findTreeHeight() ?? 0, rightChild?.findTreeHeight() ?? 0)
        }

    }
```

If I create the tree with this array:

```
let myTree = BinaryTree(arrValues: [7, 2, 5, 10, 9, 1])
```

Shouldn't the height be 4? I am getting 2.

Here's the inits and insertion functions:

```
init(value:Int) {
        self.value = value
    }

    convenience init(arrValues:Array<Int>) {

        precondition(arrValues.count > 0)
        self.init(value: arrValues.first!)
        for thisValue in arrValues.dropFirst() {
            insertValue(value: thisValue)
        }
    }

    func insertValue(value:Int) {

        if value < self.value {
            //insert on left
            if let leftChild = self.leftChild {
                leftChild.insertValue(value: value)
            } else {
                leftChild = BinaryTree(value: value)
                leftChild?.parent = self
            }
        } else {
            //insert on right
            if let rightChild = self.rightChild {
                rightChild.insertValue(value: value)
            } else {
                rightChild = BinaryTree(value: value)
                rightChild?.parent = self
            }
        }
    }
```

and an extension to pseudo print it out

```
extension BinaryTree: CustomStringConvertible {
    public var description: String {
        var s = ""
        if let left = leftChild {
            s += "(\(left.description)) <- "
        }
        s += "\(value)"
        if let right = rightChild {
            s += " -> (\(right.description))"
        }
        return s
    }
}
```

Here's the link where I was following along:

https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-algorithm-club/tree/master/Binary%20Search%20Tree

Comment: This question cannot be answered without knowing *how* the tree is constructed. A [mcve] would be helpful, and an explanation *why* you expect the result `4`.

Comment: Hey Martin, I added the inits and insertion functions to my OP.

Answer (score 1):

The height is 2 that is correct. It's the number of edges in the longest path from the node to a leaf node.

Comment: ok, I'm confused. :D 7 is the root, and the left nodes are 2, 5, 1, so wouldn't that be the height?

Comment: it would be (7 as the root, left node is 2, right node is 5) -> (then the node 2 has a left node of 10 and a right node of 9) -> (then node 5 would have a left node of 1). Although there's different ways you can interpret an array as a binary tree i'm assuming it's this. So in this case the longest path would be (and there are a few others) 7 -> 2 -> 10 Hence the height is 2

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I had to draw it out to see where I was making my mistake. Where I stumbled was thinking every insertion was looking at 7 to determine the node location.

Comment: Sorry i went through it again and it should be (7 root with left node 2 and right node 10) -> (node 2 has left node: 1 and right node: 5) -> (node 10: has left node 9). So it would be (7 -> 2 -> 1) as one of the longest paths (judging by the code given above)